# "warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary" when returning reference to static member

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constexpr

I have this class with a function that returns a value. For complicated reasons, the value needs to be returned as a `const` reference.

*(minimal working example contains an `int` array, real code has more complex objects, hence the reference)*

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999;
    const int& ret(int i) const { return i < 0 || i > 4 ? OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE : test[i]; }

private:
    int test[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
};
```

This gives me `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary` in VS2015 and it doesn't even compile with GCC.

- Adding the line `constexpr const int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS;` outside of `Foo` lets GCC compile just fine. VS2015 still gives the warning.
- Removing `constexpr` and splitting the declaration from the definition fixes the warning, but why should I have to do that?

OUT_OF_BOUNDS isn't local, and it isn't temporary, right? Does it not have an address when it is defined and declared inside of the class definition?

See the warning live: https://godbolt.org/z/fv397b9rr

Comment: anyhow, cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/e5KoKGbdW. Which gcc version are you using?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number As stated in the question, this is a MWE and the real code isn't even about integers. Also: I'm using GCC 9.0.1 (on WSL)

Comment: Compiles fine with clang, gcc and MSVC - live - https://godbolt.org/z/8r5nM5sha - please check your [mcve]

Comment: Compiles with a warning with MSVC - live https://godbolt.org/z/r69abn3rG

Comment: `static inline int OUT_OF_BOUNDS` does not show the warning, but as soon as `const` or `constexpr` is added MSVC complains. I wonder if this is a complicated case of ODR-use or a compiler bug.

Comment: @Quentin interesting. I can't use inline, since I'm on C++11, but it would have been a neat solution if it had solved the problem.

Comment: It is a compiler bug. MSVC not just issues a meaningless warning, it actually [miscompiles](https://godbolt.org/z/hrGnTWvbr) the function.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Could you explain how your example shows that MSVC miscompiles it?

Comment: `static int OUT_OF_BOUNDS;` with an out-of-line definition seems to work as well.

Comment: By looking at the assembly code. It is very obviously wrong.

Comment: There is no assembly code for MSVC in your link

Comment: Hmm indeed. It looks like a godbolt bug, it replaces msvc pane with gcc one. Change the compiler to msvc yourself. Or try [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/ETEdo8rT8), hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that in C++11, we have to add a corresponding **definition** for a **static constexpr declaration** of a class' data member. This is explained in more detail below:

#### C++11

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DECLARATION IN C++11 and C++14
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++11*,*C++14*), we have a **declaration** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. And so, in **exactly one translation unit** we have to provide a corresponding **definition**. Otherwise you'll get a **linker error** which can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xvNUCKapDg4Gelbz).

That is, in exactly one translation unit we should write:

```
constexpr const int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS;//note no initializer
```

#### C++17

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr const int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DEFINITION IN C++17
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++17*) we have a **definition** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. So since C++17, we don't have to provide the **definition** of `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` anywhere else since we already have a definition for it inside the class.

---

The warning that you're getting with *MSVC* seems to be a bug.

Comment: Strictly speaking for *VS2015* which is what the OP is using, the warning is accurate as that does not support C++17 as that didn't exist yet when that version of VS was made. If this was VS2019 or VS2022 it would be a bug If and only if they are using C++17 or C++20 modes. But it cannot be a bug when that version of the standard is not supported.

Comment: @Mgetz VS2015 does support C++11 atleast. So shouldn't it give a linker error just like gcc is giving instead of giving a warning?

Comment: It's allowed to support this via extension if it wants, the fact it's giving a warning that it's not portable is commendable for undefined behavior. That said MS has a habit of implementing draft behavior and that's likely what this is. Regardless it's not technically a bug in VS2015. You can't have a bug when it's not officially a supported requirement.

Comment: @Mgetz I think i am misunderstanding what you're saying(or vice versa). My point is that it is not about C++17. Rather it is about C++11. Since the OP is using C++11, this **must** give a linker error.(Or does it not?). I am open to being wrong. So correct me by quoting from some official source that(something that means the same as) *"VS2015 is allowed to produce a warning instead of linker error when compiling [this](https://godbolt.org/z/fv397b9rr) with C++11"*.

Comment: It's pretty clear in the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#8) *"A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs."*

Comment: @Mgetz Okay so does this mean VS2015 is allowed to compile and execute this program(with C++11) without any error? The warning that VS2015 generates is misleading. Also, are you 100% certain that this is not a bug as opposed to **n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem** comment on OP's original question?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use the `constexpr` in your function is that a temporary local instance is created. You could try to leave out `constexpr` and `static` in the declaration of your static member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS` so you have a `const` object / instance you can get a reference of.

EDIT:
If you must have a static member, declare it `const static int` and put in the definition `const int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS  = -1;` in an appropriate place.

Comment: That doesn't work - https://godbolt.org/z/Y3M775Gdq

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You have to remove ``static``, too (I edited the answer accordingly). Explanation: static members cannot be const.

Comment: Static members can very definitely be `const`. Furthermore, I require the member to be static.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of functions. You can declare it ``const static int``. Of course you have to remember to put in a definition for the static member (``const int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS  = -1;``) somewhere after the class definition.

Comment: It already says in my question that doing that indeed solves the warning. The question is: why? I don't believe that a temporary local instance is created when using a static const that is declared inside the class, but there isn't when it's declared outside the class. But if that _is_ the case: what is your source?

Answer (score -1):

`test[i]` is an `int`, you're binding it to a reference to `const int` in the return statement. No?

Comment: Yes. What is your point? Also: this is not an answer in any way, and should be a comment under my question.

Comment: My point is that the types defer. There is no valid conversion to take place here.  
Returning a `int const&` doesn't make sense anyway. But, sure, I guess that could be done. You need to `const_cast` it, though. Otherwise, `OUT_OF_BOUNDS` needs to be of type `static int`.

Comment: @T.J.Evers Also my point: that's the temporary. It's not an assignment. So I don't know that it can be valid. If it can, mark my words, it's a bug in the standard.

Comment: Returning a const reference is like saying "this function returns a reference to an integer, and you can't modify it." So returning test[i] is perfectly valid: you return a reference to the memory location `test + i` and you're stating that the caller (in this case the caller of `Foo:ret`) cannot modify that memory. There's no conversion necessary.

Comment: About returning a `const int&` not making sense: yeah, that's a bit dumb, but that's why I stated in my example that the real code doesn't use integers (but that doesn't matter for the example)

Comment: Actually, you're right. Though it did seem to solve the problem on msvc. clang is ok with [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bWsffxb9E). (I know I typed 5 instead of 4… `i > 4`… you get the point)